# How to create singleton from double check idiom for lazy initialization of instance field?

Tags: java, singleton, effective-java

```
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
    FieldType result = field;
    if (result == null) { 
        synchronized(this) {
            result = field;
            if (result == null) 
                field = result = computeFieldValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As we almost all know about this is the sample code for `double check idiom for lazy initialization of instance field`. But i have a silly doubt here how somebody will create the singleton object of FieldType. As to call the function `getField()` (which create the singleton instance) you need an instance of the class but till now you don't have the instance. I am bit confused, please let me know. Thanks!!!

Comment: @FredOverflow The problem is that `static` is missing which I don't think this question answers.

Comment: @FredOverflow thanks for your opinion. But my question is totally different. I am asking something different.

Comment: @PeterLawrey People need to stop implementing the Singleton pattern themselves when enums are so much easier and do everything right. (Or even better, scratch everything starting at "themselves".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of source the simplest singleton is an enum

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

But in this more complicated case,

> how somebody will create the singleton object of FieldType.

They have to call `getField()` which must be `static`, as does the `field`

Comment: thanks. But if you see the Effective java, Joshua Bloch mentioned exactly the same code. And specifically mentioned that `If you need to use lazy initialization for performance on an instance field, use the double-check idiom.`. Are you saying that he missed something in the book.

Comment: Eager initialization is way more performant than lazy initialization, double-checked or not. Use the lazy initialization holder class idiom, or even better enums, or even better: don't use the Singleton pattern at all.

Comment: @FredOverflow  thanks. I also know whatever you are trying to say but there is no harm in knowing  several concepts right? So i am just trying to understand what Joshua Bloch is trying to explain in his award wining book. Hope you understand my point. It's just a humble request to you no offend. Thanks.

Comment: @Trying, which is why in the 2nd edition he suggested using `enum`s indead.  Possibly because this was written after Java 5.0 was released.

Comment: @Trying The problem is that you get people repeating the same questions based on code which has been considered bad practice for almost a decade, i.e. in many case before they even started using Java.

Comment: @Trying Thanks for your kind words. I wasn't offended at all.

Answer (score 0):

As a **first RULE** of **Singleton**

```
FieldType getField()
```

should be defined as

```
public static FieldType getField()
```

so that method `getField()` (static method) of `FiledType` can be invoked, without creating instance

Of course, you need to define **private** *constructor* for `FieldType` (which was missing here)